# PuTTY Fatal Error: No supported authentication methods available

Tags: ssh, putty, authentication

I try to establish an SSH connection with the Linux server of my web hosting provider.
I receive the following error when using PuTTY Release 0.74 Build platform: 64-bit x86 Windows:
"No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic)"

1. This is what I did:
2. Generate the pair public_key - private_key
3. Give the public_key to the provider
4. Insert server's IP address and port in "Session"
5. Insert the path to my locally saved private_key in "Connection -> SSH -> Auth"
6. Save the whole configuration

Finally, if I load the configuration and try to open the connection, I receive the error message above.

Comment: *"Give the public_key to the provider"* – But did they set up the key on the server already? It looks like they did not. Show us PuTTY event log.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure whether this will resolve every incidence, and it certainly isn't the solution for cases where the public key hasn't been entered in the `authorised_keys` file on the server.

I updated PuTTY to the most recent version, and then the login worked.  So if you are having issues try installing the latest version from [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to copy the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys or make sure your cloud provider does it. I documented it with screenshots for Google Cloud here: https://www.bingehacking.net/2022/01/putty-no-supported-authentication.html

Answer (score -1):

Esse erro geralmente ocorre quando a autenticação por chave pública não está configurada corretamente ou quando o servidor não permite a autenticação por senha. Aqui estão algumas soluções que você pode tentar:

Verifique a configuração da autenticação por chave pública: Certifique-se de que a chave pública correspondente à chave privada que você está usando para se autenticar esteja presente no arquivo ~/.ssh/authorized_keys no servidor CentOS. Se a chave pública não estiver presente, você precisará adicioná-la manualmente.

Verifique as permissões dos arquivos: No servidor CentOS, verifique as permissões do diretório ~/.ssh e do arquivo ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. O diretório .ssh deve ter permissões 700 (drwx------) e o arquivo authorized_keys deve ter permissões 600 (-rw-------). Caso as permissões estejam incorretas, você pode corrigi-las usando os comandos chmod 700 ~/.ssh e chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Reinicie o serviço SSH: Em alguns casos, reiniciar o serviço SSH no servidor CentOS pode ajudar a resolver o problema. Você pode fazer isso usando o comando sudo systemctl restart sshd.

Verifique as configurações do servidor SSH: Verifique o arquivo de configuração do servidor SSH (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) no servidor CentOS. Certifique-se de que a opção PasswordAuthentication esteja definida como yes para permitir a autenticação por senha. Se você fizer alguma alteração no arquivo de configuração, lembre-se de reiniciar o serviço SSH usando sudo systemctl restart sshd.

Use o método de autenticação correto: Se você estiver usando chaves públicas para autenticação, verifique se selecionou a opção correta no Putty para especificar a chave privada correspondente. Verifique também se a chave privada está no formato adequado (geralmente formato PEM).

Espero que essas soluções ajudem a resolver o problema de autenticação no CentOS pelo Putty.

Comment: Sorry, this is an English only site.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).